# Match a range of digits and other characters with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'd like to match a range of digits and characters to replace them with `sed`; a Perl-like regex I would tend to write would be:

```
[\d-_]+
```

to match, for example, digits and dashes and underscores. It works like a charm with `grep`:

```
$  more sed_example.txt 
something 2021-04-21_08-45_file
some other thing 2021-04-21_08-15_test
and so on
$ grep -P "[\d-_]+" sed_example.txt
something 2021-04-21_08-45_file
some other thing 2021-04-21_08-15_test
```

So now I'd like to do the same with sed, but even with extended expressions (`-r`) I cannot use `\d` and I cannot combine ranges like `[0-9]` or `[[:digits:]]` with other characters, or at least I did not find the way. A solution would be to explicitely list all digits, but I am a bit too lazy for that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your range `[\d-_]` does not make sense (there is no range starting from `\d` and running until `_`). Did you mean `[\d_-]`?

The POSIX equivalent of `[\d_-]` is `[[:digit:]_-]` or `[0-9_-]`.  Note that to include a literal dash in the bracket expression, it has to occur first or last.

```
$ grep -o '[[:digit:]_-]\{1,\}' file
2021-04-21_08-45_
2021-04-21_08-15_
```

```
$ sed -n 's/.* \([[:digit:]_-]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p' file
2021-04-21_08-45_
2021-04-21_08-15_
```

Note that I have to match the space in front of the first digit here, otherwise I only capture the `_` at the end.

You could also use a more specific regular expression that actually tries to match something on the form that you're looking for and not just any digit, dash, or underscore:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_\).*/\1/p' file
2021-04-21_08-45_
2021-04-21_08-15_
```

---

```
$ tr -d -c '\n[:digit:]_-' <file | tr -s '\n'
2021-04-21_08-45_
2021-04-21_08-15_
```

Here I'm using `tr` to delete all non-digits, non-newlines, non-underscores and non-dashes.  Then I'm using it again to squeeze multiple consecutive newlines into single ones.

Comment: OK thanks, my mistake was therefore the order of the characters I didn't think of the "double" meaning of the dash character. Thanks for the other solutions but for the first one it was a made out example (and I am a bit allergic to expressions to specific). The second one is way too dangerous (I have other numbers and dashes and all I don't want to squash).